# CSS How to fix element position after some scroll without using jquery

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want an element of my websites's sidebar to be fixed after some scrolling. The functionality i'm searching is the same used by 9gag website here: http://9gag.com/gag/abq3PbX?ref=fsidebar (specifically the last square ads that is fixed when you scroll down the page from some point). How can i do the same without using jquery or other external libraries, but using css/javascript only?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've done by switching between 'fixed' and 'absolute' regarding the document's body scrollTop.

```
function scrollFunction() {
    var scrollPos = document.body.scrollTop;

    if (scrollPos > 40) {
        document.getElementById("fixed-floater").style.position = "fixed";
        document.getElementById("fixed-floater").style.top = "0px";
    } else {
        document.getElementById("fixed-floater").style.position = "absolute";
        document.getElementById("fixed-floater").style.top = "40px";
    }
}

window.onscroll = scrollFunction;
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ua4fhrzy/1/

But you might consider looking into "sticky css"

Comment: Thank you that is what i was searching for.